# How do i remove text from back button on navbar within Xcode?

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, back-button

I set an arrow custom image to navigation bar by adding the following code in app delegate, it works but now im looking to remove the text completely for back button.

```
UIImage * backButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed: @"BackButtonGrey.png"];
backButtonImage = [backButtonImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth: 15.0 topCapHeight: 30.0];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance]  setBackButtonBackgroundImage: backButtonImage  forState: UIControlStateNormal  barMetrics: UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just did it like this, worked fine for me :-)

```
UIImage *backButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationBarBack.png"];
UIButton *backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[backButton setImage:backButtonImage
            forState:UIControlStateNormal];

backButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, backButtonImage.size.width, backButtonImage.size.height);

[backButton addTarget:self
               action:@selector(popViewController)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backBarButtonItem;
```

Comment: I wanted to try and do it in app delegate so its changed globally instead of pasting this code on each controller classes.

Comment: You could subclass UIViewController, add the code there and use this class for your controllers.

Comment: Mh ok.. double checked it, seems like its not working this way.. sorry for that.. Then I think you should go the subclassing way.

Comment: how would i go about doing that sub classing?

Comment: I used a category, where I put a method with the code from my answer and just called it in each controller, where I wanted to use the custom back button.. If you're using a subclass, you'll just create one inheriting from UIViewController, put that code in viewDidLoad. Create your other viewController to inherit from that viewController and call [super viewDidLoad] in viewDidLoad (which you should do anyway).

Comment: however, this will disable swipe back gesture in iOS 7

Answer (score 9):

Simply move the text vertically so far that it no longer appears. This can be done at app launch in your app delegate.

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0, 20.f) forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Normally this call is for tweaking the vertical text position which can vary depending on the font used. Here the text is moved far enough that it's no longer inside the Back button view, and so is clipped into non-existence.

Comment: As far as I've experienced this doesn't do anything with the offset of the current view controllers title.

Comment: Yup agree @Ronny-André Bendiksen - this will still cause long titles to get offset which looks weird

Answer (score 9):

I really don't think is a good practice for a developer to adjust the offset of the text in order to hide it.

A cleaner solution would be to just add to the navigation controller back button a new button where the title is an empty string. You should add this in the previous calling view controller in viewWillAppear (not the current one):

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

Comment: This is the only answer that ended up working for me.  Make sure you pay attention to *You should add this in the previous calling view controller*!

Comment: This is the best answer!

Answer (score 6):

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(-100.f, 0) forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: UIOffsetMake(-100.f, 0)

This is not good at all - if you will come in this view controller by standard push, you will see moved text while animation. Better might be for example:

UIOffsetMake(-100.f, -5000.f)

Answer (score 1):

Do not use the appearance proxy. Instead, for *every* view controller, put this code into its `viewDidLoad` implementation:

```
UIImage * backButtonImage = 
    [UIImage imageNamed: @"BackButtonGrey.png"];
backButtonImage = 
    [backButtonImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth: 15.0 topCapHeight: 30.0];

UIBarButtonItem* b =
     [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
          initWithImage:backButtonImage
          style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = b;
```

That will cause the *next* view controller pushed onto the navigation stack to have a back button consisting of just the image.

(However, I should point out that `stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:...` is deprecated. You should be using `resizableImage...`.)

Comment: Then you didn't do what I said. I use this code and my back button is fine.

Comment: I tried using your code but i end with the same plain back button and nothing custom

Comment: Read my answer more carefully. If you have that code in view controller A, you will see that back button *not* in view controller A's view but in view controller B's view when view controller B is pushed onto view controller A.

Answer (score 1):

To set a backbutton text, you set a new backbutton to the current viewController before pushing or presenting then new one which would show the text of the backbutton:

In your current viewController (not the new one which will show the back-button):

```
vc                                    = [[MyNewViewController alloc]initWith...];
vc.title                              = @"New ViewController";
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

So if you want to remove the text, just use `@""` as a title for the new backbutton.

To set a backbutton-icon for the entire app, use the following code in your appDelegate class. Not every icon fits perfectly, so if you have to move it around a little, you can use the "backInsets". In my example the icon will move 2px down.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    ...
    ...
    [self customBackButtonIcon];
    return YES;
}

- (void)customBackButtonIcon
{        
    UIEdgeInsets backInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, -2, 0);
    UIImage *backImg = [[[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_button_white"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal] imageWithAlignmentRectInsets:backInsets];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorImage:backImg];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorTransitionMaskImage:backImg];
}
```

Tested with iOS9

Comment: Alternatively you can put self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = .... into your setup / viewDidLoad method on your current viewController which pushes the new one.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIBarButtonItem *newBackButton =
[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                 style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                target:nil
                                action:nil];
[[self navigationItem] setBackBarButtonItem:newBackButton];
```

Answer (score -1):

Perfect solution globally

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.clearColor()], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.clearColor()], forState: UIControlState.Highlighted)

    return true
}
```