# UINavigation set back button image instead of the <Back text Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uiimage

I am trying to change the Back button within the `UINavigationController`. This is what I tried so far and the output:

> 1

Code within the `ViewDidLoad`

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "navBarBackButton")
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = UIImage(named: "navBarBackButton")
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.image = UIImage(named: "navBarBackButton")
```

Output:

[image: Nav Back Button]

I tried to add the below but id didn't help:

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title:"", style:.Plain, target:nil, action:nil)
```

> 2

Code within the `AppDelegate`

```
let backImg: UIImage = UIImage(named: "navBarBackButton")!
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setBackButtonBackgroundImage(backImg, forState: .Normal, barMetrics: .Default)
```

Output:

[image: Nav Back Button]

> 3

I tried to add the back button in `Storyboard` but nothing changed

[image: Nav Back Button]

> 4 - Thanks to sanandiya vipul. Still need it to be instead of the 'Back'. This only deletes the 'Back but keeps the image lower right side instead of the entire '

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffsetMake(0, -80.0), forBarMetrics: .Default)
```

This is the output:

[image: Back Button]

> This is the result I am hoping to achieve

[image: Back Button]

Comment: May be this link has the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12886274/storyboard-uinavigation-controller-back-button-text?rq=1

The second answer having 10 votes

Comment: I tried that solution but didn't work. Please see my third output

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27499998/how-to-set-image-for-bar-button-with-swift show this link and tell done or not

Comment: Thanks @Birendra but my question is how to override the back button, not create a new bar button item. Thanks

Comment: hi you got solution?

Comment: Working on it now, will post once I have a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Below Code add your ViewDidLoad method. its work for you fine.

for **Swift**

> UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffsetMake(0, -80.0), forBarMetrics: .Default)

for **Objective-c**

> [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0,- 80.f) forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

Comment: Thanks, do you have it in Swift? Tried to convert but UIOffsetMake is not an option

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501258/how-do-i-remove-text-from-back-button-on-navbar-within-xcode     see it

Comment: Thanks! for some reason first time when I go to the VC, it shows '<Back' and second time it shows the image. Any idea why it only executes after?

Comment: I added to a top VC and it works fine! I still see the image very small. I will post the 4th try to show what I get. Hope you can help

Comment: @TalZion Any solution that worked for you? I am having a similar issue. Let me know, if you got your expected result.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4 version**

Set Back title text color to clear

```
let barButtonItemAppearance = UIBarButtonItem.appearance()        
barButtonItemAppearance.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.clear], for: .normal)                
barButtonItemAppearance.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.clear], for: .highlighted)
```

Answer (score -1):

Just added `UIBarButtonItem` and linked it to action.

```
    @IBAction func backTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Swift 5 version**

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffset(horizontal: 0, vertical: -80.0), for: .default)
```